# Pynsist + Basemap - ImportError: no module named '_geoslib'

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, pynsist

I'm trying to use pynsist with basemap. I'm starting with the pynsist 'Guess the Number' example. I'm on Windows, using python 3.5.1.

Creating the program with `pynsist installer.cfg` and installing it work fine, but when I try to run the installed program I get `ImportError: No module named ...` for various modules. I added modules to the `[Include]` section of `installer.cfg` to fix these import errors. After adding these modules, the include section of `installer.cfg` is

```
[Include]
packages=guessnumber
    mpl_toolkits
    matplotlib
    six
    numpy
    pyparsing
    cycler
    dateutil
```

With these, I still get the error `ImportError: No module named '_geoslib'` when I run the installed program.

How do I fix this error?

The entire example application can be found at https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/tree/master/examples/console

and the only modifications I've made to it are

1. the `[Include]` section installer.cfg shown above
2. adding `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` to the top of `guessnumber.py`

Comment: For anyone reading this, we're investigating on a Github issue: https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/issues/128#issuecomment-332384496